# shinydashboard: change font size of menuItem in sidebarMenu

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a dashboardSideBar with some tabs and a some select input (below). I want to change the size of the menuItem but not the selectizeInput. Furthermore I want to keep the old styles of the menuItem such as changing color on hover - but just change the size of the font.

```
  dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Tab1", tabName="tab1")
      ),
      selectizeInput(inputId = "x", label = "y", choices = "z")
    )
```

A similar question was asked and this was suggested:

```
tags$style(HTML(".main-sidebar { font-size: 20px; }"))
```

However this changes everything in the sidebar including by select inputs which I do not want.

I have tried using divs however this removes all the previous formatting and doesn't look very good. If someone knows how to reference these specific items in css hopefully that would work. E.g. .menu-item, although this is not the correct reference.

Comment: It is not a duplicate as this method changes everything in the sidebar. I only want to change the menuItems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work: `tags$style(HTML(".sidebar-menu li a { font-size: 30px; }"))`

***Edit:***
This is derived from the structure of the HTML that Shiny produces.

It basically means: change the font size to 30, only for texts that are inside an `<a>` element (which is actually a link - in this case the tab button is considered a link), providing that the `<a>` element is inside an `<li>` element (which is actually a list - in this case the list of tabs), and providing that the `<li>` element is inside any element with the class `sidebar-menu`.

Comment: Thanks a lot I spent ages trying to do this. Could you explain what "li" and "a" mean and why this works?

Comment: Great I'm happy it helped. Re your question see the edit to the answer above. For more info I'd recommend this great tutorial: https://flukeout.github.io/